# Get NFT owner by contract & token Id

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-721, nft, erc-1155

I am trying to get the owner of a NFT in `solidity` & `web3` by calling `the Contract` and `the token id`

In `Web3.js-v1.3.5` I've tried this so far, but the result isn't ever calledBack!

How can I handle this? and how can I write this in `solidity` as well ?

```
        var abi_ = [ {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ownerOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }]

    const smartContractAddress = "0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e"
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi_, smartContractAddress)
    let owner = await contract.methods.ownerOf('91338127118827779192862936396890434745733899848224782300810335984505495486465').call()
    //Code never reaches here
    console.log(owner)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this abi:

```
 {"constant":true,"inputs":
  [{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],
 "name":"ownerOf",
 "outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],
 "payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}
```

You forgot to put the owner address of the Contract in "from" place:

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e', {
    from: '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891', //<--- here 
    gasPrice: '20000000000' 
});
```